# Latin-extended characters get displaced in a table when font-weight:bold

Tags: html, css

Latin extended characteres (Scarons, Š,Č,Ž) get displaced in a table row when font-weight is set to bold, I have no idea why and I have never seen anything like it.

I am attaching some screenshots below.

[image: font-weight:normal]
[image: font-weight:bold]

EDIT: I think it might be a font issue, if I swap to Arial it works ok. How could that be?

Comment: Might this be a line-height issue?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've tried increasing line-height, it is not a line-height issue :/

Comment: Fonts are code. They can have bugs in. Fonts can compose multiple outlines to form a single glyph - it looks like the font code here is putting the carons in the wrong place relative to the base letter glyph. The bold version of the font is a separate file - it could easily just be a bug in the bold font. If it happens in all browsers (you don't mention what browser you're using) you should report it to the font vendor. If it only happens in some browsers, report it to the browser vendors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a font bug, definitely. May be caused by different OS, because font rendering algorithm differs from one OS to another.
Try to contact to the font developer and ask for fixing that issue.